# Create different results in different tabs using R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, classification, shiny-server

I am new to R shiny. I have created one web application by writing below code. Here i need some modification.

1. I want to create two buttons(Ex: Output, Accuracy)
2. When users clicks the Output button it should show the output values `print(final1)`.
3. When user clicks the Accuracy button, it should show the Confusion 
   Matrix(cm) `print(caret::confusionMatrix(cm2))`.

Could anyone please help me. Below is the code:

```
runApp(
list(
ui = fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Upload & Results"),



  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(


      fileInput('file1', 'Choose Excel File',accept = c(".xlsx")

      )
    ),

    mainPanel(

      tableOutput('contents'))

  )
),
server = function(input, output){
  output$contents <- renderTable({

    req(input$file1)

    inFile <- input$file1





    df_test=read_excel(inFile$datapath, 1)
    df1_test =  subset(df_test, select=c("Number"    ,                    
                                         "Category"       ,"Country"   ,                     
                                         "State"  , "Region","PkValue" ,"ASTvalue" ,"DMValue" ,"Geo","Demo"))




    Probabilty_Score = predict(classifier, type = 'response',newdata = df1_test)
    Output = as.factor(ifelse(Probabilty_Score<0.55,0,1))

    cm2 = table(df_test$Result, Output)

    print(caret::confusionMatrix(cm2))

    final=df_test[,c("Number","Result")]
    final1=cbind(final,Output,Probabilty_Score)    

    print(final1)






  })
}
)
)
```

Comment: I checked your profile and it seems that you are not aware of this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers I am not forcing you to accept my answer but kindly adopt the best practices.

Comment: @SaurabhChauhan.. Thanks for your valuable comment.. Yeah i am new to here , currently i  am working on your code.

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't provide sample data, I can only give you more or less of a guess that (hopefully) works as intended. I know you wanted to have two actions buttons, but I consider adding an input switch from the `shinyWidgets` package the cleaner option. I added comments where I changed something in your code. Please try it out with your data and tell me if it's working.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets) # You'll need this to get the switch widget
runApp(
  list(
    ui = fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Upload & Results"),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          fileInput('file1', 'Choose Excel File',accept = c(".xlsx")), # don't forget a "," here

          #XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
          # Add a switch
          switchInput("input_switch",
                      "change",
                      value=T,
                      onLabel="Output",
                      offLabel="Accuracy")
          #XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

        ),

        mainPanel(
          tableOutput('contents'))
      )
    ),
    server = function(input, output){

      output$contents <- renderTable({
        req(input$file1)
        inFile <- input$file1
        df_test=read_excel(inFile$datapath, 1)
        df1_test =  subset(df_test, select=c("Number"    ,                    
                                             "Category"       ,"Country"   ,                     
                                             "State"  , "Region","PkValue" ,"ASTvalue" ,"DMValue" ,"Geo","Demo"))

        Probabilty_Score = predict(classifier, type = 'response',newdata = df1_test)
        Output = as.factor(ifelse(Probabilty_Score<0.55,0,1))
        cm2 = table(df_test$Result, Output)

        final=df_test[,c("Number","Result")]
        final1=cbind(final,Output,Probabilty_Score)    

        #XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        # Determine output depending on switch
        if(input$input_switch){
          print(caret::confusionMatrix(cm2))
        }else{
          print(final1)
        }
        #XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

      })
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Now it is working fine. Initially it was showing some error:cannot coerce class ‘"confusionMatrix"’ to a data.frame.. Then i change little bit in my code:if(input$input_switch){
          print((cm2))
        }else{
          print(final1)
        }

Comment: Now it is working fine. I think it is not able to show the whole confusion matrix as a data frame..So i will manually calculate and create new DF to publish.

Comment: Hey Alex, could you please help  me how can we do with the help of  only two buttons.

Comment: The post underneath already shows you how to do it. You need two actionButtons and two observers, that print your output.

Answer (score 1):

We can add two `buttons` (as pointed in the question) in the `UI` code as follow:

```
  actionButton("output", "Output"),  # Button to get Output
  actionButton("accuracy", "Accuracy") # Button to get accuracy
```

Now, we can observe the button click event as follow (without data I am not sure whether the following code is working or not):

```
observeEvent(input$output, {
   print(final1)    # Print the outvalues here as button Output is clicked
})

observeEvent(input$accuracy, {
   print(caret::confusionMatrix(cm2))   # Print confusion matrix here as button accuracy is clicked
})
```

**Updated code:**

```
  runApp(
  list(
    ui = fluidPage(

      titlePanel("Upload & Results"),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          fileInput('file1', 'Choose Excel File',accept = c(".xlsx")),
          actionButton("output", "Output"),  # Button to get Output
          actionButton("accuracy", "Accuracy") # Button to get accuracy 
        ),

        mainPanel(
          fixedRow(
            column(10,DT::dataTableOutput("contents")) 
          )
        )
     )
    ),
    server = function(input, output){
      output$contents <- renderDataTable({


        req(input$file1)
        inFile <- input$file1
        df_test=read_excel(inFile$datapath, 1)
        df1_test =  subset(df_test, select=c("Number"    ,                    
                                             "Category"       ,"Country"   ,                     
                                             "State"  , "Region","PkValue" ,"ASTvalue" ,"DMValue" ,"Geo","Demo"))


        Probabilty_Score = predict(classifier, type = 'response',newdata = df1_test)
        Output = as.factor(ifelse(Probabilty_Score<0.55,0,1))

        cm2 = table(df_test$Result, Output)

        final=df_test[,c("Number","Result")]
        final1=cbind(final,Output,Probabilty_Score)  

        observeEvent(input$output, {
          print(final1)    # Print the outvalues here as button Output is clicked
        })

        observeEvent(input$accuracy, {
          print(caret::confusionMatrix(cm2))   # Print confusion matrix here as button accuracy is clicked
        })

        # In the following line, return data.frame that you would like to see
        return(DT::datatable(iris, options = list(pageLength = 10)))
      })
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually i am getting one error.  "Error:cannot coerce class ‘c("Observer", "R6")’ to a data.frame".. Could you please help me .

Comment: I think that is your `data.frame` problem. I can't say anything without looking your data.

Comment: I am working on this, i will let you know once it is done.

Comment: I need your small help..i am getting an error while executing the above code. Error is :**cannot coerce class ‘c("Observer", "R6")** to a data.frame"...No problem in the data frame.Could you please help me

Comment: Can you please share data using `dput(head(df_test))`?

Comment: Actually this is an issue. I can not share data, i don't have that privilege.

Comment: @PANDA: If an answer from alex_555 is working then consider that an answer. Is it working for you?

Comment: Yeah that is working, but i want to have two actions buttons only. There i am getting 3 buttons.

Comment: @PANDA: I have added the updated solution. Could you please check and let me know your views? Thank you

Comment: Thanks Saurabh.. I am getting an error: ** Error in sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(fileInput("file1", "Choose Excel File",  : 
  unused argument (server = function(input, output) {
    output$contents <- renderDataTable({
        req(input$file1)
        inFile <- input$file1 **

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187993/discussion-between-saurabh-chauhan-and-panda).

Comment: When i changed to renderPrint in our previous code,it is  showing results , but in R studio not in the R Shiny app. Can we do anything to publish in shiny app.